# LESS property loading inconsistently in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

I am compiling my LESS file by adding the less.js in my index.html. My code is something as follows:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less"/> <!--my own styles go in this file -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="blue-text">Hello</div>
  <div class="blue-background"></div>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="less.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script> <!--my own script file -->
</body>


//style.less
.blue-text {
  color: blue;
}

//script.js
(function(){
  $('.blue-background').css('background', $('.blue-text').css('color'));
})();
```

Now when I render this page in the browser it renders fine in the Chrome browser. 
But in Firefox the blue-background does not get the colour everytime. It comes sometimes and sometimes it does not.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because different browsers behaves differently when rendering the pages.

In your case the script.js is run before the less file has been compiled into the css file. so it can't read from the blue-text class that it would apply it on the blue-background because that class is not yet available to the dom yet.

The only solution is you have to manually compile the less into css and use the css in the html file so that you are sure that your less compiles before your page renders.

if you hate to do it manually everytime, you can use some automated javascript task runners like i use [Gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/).